# ASP.Net GridView selected row changes during edit

Tags: asp.net, datagridview

I have a asp.net gridview control with editing enabled. I have persisted selection enabled and datakeynames set up as well on the datagridview control. If a record is inserted into the table before I click the edit hyperlink when the page refreshes row that is selected for editing is incorrect. It seems that the row index is being remembered instead of the key specified in the datkeynames.

Comment: Your description is little confusing. What exactly are you trying? Is it like this: You insert a new record, you then want to edit the newly inserted record & then ..?

Comment: I have a page that inserts records and a page for editing records. If a record is inserted by another user between the time of your initial "edit" page load and when you click the "edit link" when the page refreshes for the edit action all of the records are shifted down one spot (because a new record was inserted) and the row that you are able to edit is shifted so you are editing the incorrect row.